# How dynamic is LESS CSS?

Tags: css, less

I am writing this with no experience of using LESS. However I just wanted to know that if I have a LESS stylesheet for a page and a client viewing the page say changes the size of the page, can I have custom rules which sets the pixel value of an element if the page is resized to say less than 50% or can dynamically change the font of a heading on page resize?

Comment: You can do that without less already. Ever heard of media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **YES**

:)